# Block offensive words

Tags: discussion, offensive

Is there anyway to block a word instead of totally blocking the friend? I find F*CK extremely offensive. In addition I have young people as friends, and they should not be subjected to this language either. This word constantly turns up in various items as well as some people typing it.  I've asked people not to use it, but they only read their posts. I am sure there would be others that would like to have this word blocked as well.

Comment: Upon a second read of your question and the use of the word "friend", are you talking about the Stack Exchange family of sites, or something different altogether?

Comment: Related: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html)

Comment: And it's even [a programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck)...

Comment: Clbuttic! Clbuttic I say! I say Clbuttic, sir!

Comment: Are you talking about _chat_ ? This 'blocking the friend' thing is only possible there. And no, we're not filtering bad words in chat - that would lead to a prolific outbreak of bad words _here_.

Comment: Clbuttic mistake...

Comment: I would like to see some way to hide 'offensive' words in chat. Most of the time if you just remove them from a sentence then there is no effect on it's meaning. I can understand swearing when speaking but when typing all the extra effort for no gain I just don't get.

Comment: This looks like a Facebook support request to me.

Comment: @Flexo Yeah, I was wondering the same. Let's see if the OP ever comes back to confirm or deny this...

Answer (score 11):

Word filters are bad things and often cause more problems than they solve. However, a user should not use offensive words to begin with. If there is no valid reason to use them, they should be edited out of the posts they are in, or their comments containing them should be flagged. If you're referring to such words used in chat, you have the option to flag such messages as well.

I feel that any of those options more than adequately deals with the situation. If a user goes on to keep using offensive language, at some point a moderator attention flag explaining the situation might be in order.